# pymongo insert inside the loop

Tags: insert, pymongo

all I have a tricky problem about pymongo insert inside the loop, Why the result is only first record if I use insert() or is the last record if I use save().

```
from pymongo import Connection

m = Connection(config.get('server'))
mdb = m[config.get('db_name')]

cond = {
    'corp_fax_no'  : u'5667767', 
    'corp_area_id' : 12L, 
    'corp_url'     : u'http://www.example.com', 
    'corp_id'      : 1L, 
    'corp_addr'    : u'some thing', 
    'corp_post_no' : u'220940', 
    'corp_email'   : u'123@123.com', 
    'corp_tel_no'  : u'714-717-2265'
}

@tool.timeit
def test_insert_mongo():
    cn = '{0}'.format(config.get("coll_timetest"))
    coll = mdb[cn]
    for i in xrange(10000):
        print i
        cond.update({'corp_id':i})
        coll.insert(cond)

test_insert_mongo()
```

I just insert 10000 entries in Mongo, But I can only find one entry. Why?

Answer (score 5):

If the document passed to `collection.insert()` does not contain `_id`, it will be added on save (see [pymongo api](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.8/api/pymongo/collection.html)). This means that after the first call, the document **does** have an `_id` and thus will **not** be inserted again.

If you call `collection.save()` the stored document is updated and you'll end up with a single doc with the last value passed as corp_id.

A simple 'fix' would be to remove the `_id` key from the dict on each iteration, prior to calling .insert():

```
for i in xrange(10000):
    cond.update({'corp_id':i})
    cond.pop('_id', None)
    coll.insert(cond)
```